# Use headless chrome to automate Facebook posts

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-headless

Is it possible to post on a `facebook` group using `Headless Chrome`? I need this to automate posting some messages on a group.

I managed to login in to facebook but I'm stuck at this point...

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

CDP((protocol) => {
    const {Page, Runtime} = protocol;

Promise.all([
    Page.enable(),
    Runtime.enable()
]).then(() => {
    Page.navigate({url: 'https://www.facebook.com'});
    Page.loadEventFired(() => {
        const js = 'document.getElementById("email").value="my_email";document.getElementById("pass").value="SlidSelfby92";document.getElementById("loginbutton").click()';
        Runtime.evaluate({expression: js}).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            setTimeout(function () {
                Runtime.evaluate({expression: "document.getElementsByClassName('_2s25')[0].href"}).then(result => {
                    Page.navigate({url: result.result.value});
                })
            },5000)
        });
    });
});

}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

If this is not possible, then does anyone know how can I post to facebook using an API Call?

Comment: use the graph api. if there is no way with the api, don´t do it. rule of thumb.

Comment: information about posting to groups can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/group/feed#publish

Comment: @luschn basically at this moment the only way to post on a facebook group is using `Sharing products`, which means that I can't automate this at all ... am I correct?

Comment: that is correct, yes.